# How to sort items alphabetically after a group by in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent

I have an eloquent query like this;

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->with('translation', 'category')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('category.name');
```

How can I sort the products alphabetically? So the results will look like this;

```
categoryName1:
    a
    b
    c
categoryName2:
    a
    b
    c
```

I understand that I can't use the `->with` but need to use joins. Still I don't get it to work with what I tried:

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
    ->join('product_translations', 'product_translations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->orderBy('product_translations.title', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('category.name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. The sample you give with `categoryName a/b/c` is contradictory to what you do in the query. You can't get all the individual products if you group them by category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the desired results simply by using `sortBy`. I already had a collection of the results. I used `orderBy` which of course will not work with collections. I was confused because I thought I worked with a query because of `::query()`.

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->with('translation', 'category')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('translation.title')
    ->groupBy('category.name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your query. It have to be categories.name.

```
$products = Product::query()
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
    ->join('product_translations', 'product_translations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->orderBy('product_translations.title', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('categories.name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: what issue are you having ?